# Php mail pulling form data from previous page

Tags: php, html, css, email

So I have a form being filled out on one php like so:

```
<p>
  <label for="first_name">First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="first_name" id="first_name"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="last_name"> Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="last_name" id="last_name"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="address_street">Street:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="address_street" id="address_street"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="address_city">City:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="address_city" id="address_city"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="address_state">State/Province:</label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="address_state" id="address_state"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="email">Your  e-mail: </label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email"/>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="phone">Your phone number: </label>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="phone" id="phone"/>
</p>
```

This is on one php page. From here, it goes to another php which part of it contains script to send a html email to recipient.

Problem is, I cannot seem to get it to pull the variables even though I thought I declared them correctly and mixed them into the html correctly.

```
<?php
  $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $to = "devtech8@gmail.com, example@gmail.com";
  $subject = "HTML email for ALPS";

  $message .= '
  <html>
    <body>
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 28%; float: left;">
        <img src="http://englishintheusa.com/images/alps-logo.jpg" alt="ALPS Language School" />
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; width: 68%; float: right;">
        <p style="color: #4F81BD; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: underline;">Thanks You For Your Inquiry!</p>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-left: 20px; color: #666666; font-size: 16.8px; clear: both;">
        <p>Dear $first_name $last_name ,</p>
        </br >
        <p>Thank you for the following inquiry:</p>
        </br >
        </br >
        </br >
        </br >
        <p>****Comment goes here****</p>
        </br >
        </br >
        <p>We will contact you within 2 business days.  Our office is open Monday-Friday, 8:30 AM - 5:00 PM Pacific Standard Time.</p>
        </br >
        <p>Thank you for your interest!</p>
        </br >
        </br >
        <p>Best Regards,</p>
        </br >
        </br >
        <p>ALPS Language School</p>
        </br >
        </br >
        <p>430 Broadway East</p>
        <p>Seattle WA 98102</p>
        <p>Phone: 206.720.6363</p>
        <p>Fax: 206. 720.1806</p>
        <p>Email: info@englishintheusa.com</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>';

  // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

  // More headers

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

So you see where I am trying to get `first_name` and `last_name`. Well it doesn't come out correctly.

Can someone help here?

Comment: Additionally, the </br> are not doing their job. Can this not be this way when embedded in php?

Comment: Do you have an action and method in your form?

Comment: `font-size: 16.8px;` ? wow, so accurate. You didn't show your `<form>` tag

Comment: Change `</br >` to `<br />` for starters.

Comment: Here is the form tag: <form  action="http://www.englishintheusa.com/students_conf.php" method="post" id="contactform">

Comment: Thought maybe a php include was needed somewhere, but that didnt do anything but mess it up.

Comment: @Mark: You don't need a semi-colon (`;`) after the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag. And, unless you are using `$message` earlier, you should say `$message = 'foo bar';` rather than `$message .= 'foo bar';`. The same would apply the first time you use `$headers`. Correct these, and post here if you still have problems.

Comment: I am still having issues. Have tried numerous things. It does send the email, but the variable are never pull. As mentioned earlier, these are form inputs on the previous page. So here is what I have:

Comment: 'code'<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$to = 'devtech8@gmail.com, example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'HTML email for ALPS';

$message = '
<html>
<body>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 28%; float: left;">
<img src="http://englishintheusa.com/images/alps-logo.jpg" alt="ALPS Language School" />
</div>

<div style="padding-left: 20px; color: #666666; font-size: 16.8px; clear: both;">
<p>Dear <?php ".$first_name." -?> ,</p>
'code'

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
```

it will fetch the data from request sent in cookie,post or get.

Comment: it does not relate to the question. The question does not provide enough information (e.g. `<form>` tag)

Comment: but, if he is using the <form> to submit the data then we can fetch it with given lines.

Comment: true, but the scope of getting variables should be as precise as possible, to avoid possible conflict of variables (e.g. `$_GET['first_name'] != $_POST['first_name']`)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
....'+$variables+'...
```

because when you use the '' you cant get a value from variable you need, use "" to call a variable

for example

```
<?php 
    $t = 'test';
    echo "$t"; // will result test
    echo '$t'; // will result $t
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error is because the `<form>` tag is incorrect. It should be:

```
<form action="students_conf.php" method="post" id="contactform">
```